# ImportHTML recalculation by the minute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am trying to get the data on my google sheet to be recalculate every minute

by using this script.

```
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var r = "A1";
    var f = '=ImportHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/","table")';
    sh.getRange(r).setFormula(f);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-1).setValues(sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-1).getValues());
  }
```

but I got a a #REF error in the sheet

[image]

I just want the data been recalculated

any help ?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Have you got your function set up on a trigger? 2) Why do you move the data range with `sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-1).setValues(sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-1).getValues());`? The data *is* being recalculated on load of the function, but you're getting a `#REF` error because of moving the values and asking the formula to overwrite the newly placed data.

Comment: 1 - yes 
2 I just copy and paste da script 

Now I am using this :

function getData() { 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet7"); 
  var queryString = Math.random(); 
  var cellFunction = '=importjson("https://blockchain.info/ticker")';

    sheetName.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction); 
}   

Can you help ?

Comment: This new script works but I don't see the new data only old or some minutes before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can do this by clearing the Sheet and re-loading the formula, on a time-based Installable trigger.*

#### Code:

```js
function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = "A1";
  var f = '=ImportHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/","table")';
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(r).setFormula(f);
}

function getData2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var r = "A1";
  var f = '=ImportHTML("https://bitinfocharts.com/","table")';
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(r).setFormula(f);
}
```

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: but....
''unction getData2() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var r = "A1";
  var f = '=ImportHTML("https://bitinfocharts.com/","table")';
  sh.clear();
  sh.getRange(r).setFormula(f);
  
}''

I can't add this script together with the other one on tab 2 or Sheet 2

Comment: `'Function getData2() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var r = "A1";
  var f = '=ImportHTML("https://bitinfocharts.com/","table")';
  sh.clear();
  sh.getRange(r).setFormula(f);
  
} `

Comment: Thank you it did work 

would it work for API formulas as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by `would it work for API formulas`?

Comment: I have try to find a way to get the data quick in the google sheets . lots of Bitcoin data sites the offer API , Json, etc... 
The easiest one is that one I posted

Comment: but it does not seem that the data has been changing every min . I set the triggers for 1 minute , but the data does not change

Comment: You might be calling the API at a shorter interval than it updates data. Each time the script runs it re-calls the API.